# Jasper report with excel data source

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

I have created, using a jasper designer (not iReport but a plugin for eclipse), a report that uses an excel file as datasource.
the report works fine, in the designer,  and read the data from the file without problems but after compiling the file to `file.jasper` and giving him the excel file's path nothing apears in the JasperViewer!
This is my code:

```
try{
      Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      parameters.put("DataFile", "jasper_export.xls");
      JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(new FileInputStream(new File("file.jasper")), parameters,conn);

      JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
      jv.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
This code woks perfect:

```
try{
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("param_name", paramValue);

    ExcelDataSource ds = new ExcelDataSource(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(excelFilePath));
    String[] columnNames = new String[]{"id", "nom", "iden", "adress", "activity", "compta"};
    ds.setColumnNames(columnNames);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(new FileInputStream(new File(yourJasperFilePath)), parameters, ds);
    JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();

   }
```